# Windows Batch Scripting with Dsget user -sid

Tags: windows, batch-file

I create this simple command:

dsget user -sid %UserName%

And it yields this output:

```
sid
S-1-5-21-438975769-448141152-163212925-1186
dsget succeeded
```

I only want the middle line. What needs to be done to reveal just that?

Answer (score 3):

```
dsget user -sid %UserName% | find "S-"
```

as only a SID starts with "S-".

Comment: I found the Find command helped, after I placed this post. That solution is a bit better than the one I used. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```bat
@echo off
for /f "eol=d skip=1" %%a in (
    'dsget user -sid %username%'
) do echo(%%a
```

In non server OS's two alternatives are:

The built-in WMIC command. *(this allows you to replace `%username%` as necessary for other, not current users)*.

```bat
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%a in (
    '"wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid"'
) do for %%b in (%%a) do echo(%%b
```

Or the built-in WhoAmI for the currently logged in user only, you could try:

```bat
@echo off
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%a in (
    'whoami /user /FO CSV /NH') do echo(%%a
```